# Как написать нестандартную функцию суммы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Сгенерировать десять списков из случайных чисел.
Вывести их и сумму их элементов на экран. Найти среди них один с максимальной суммой элементов.
Указать какой он по счету, повторно вывести этот список и сумму его элементов.
Заполнение списка и подсчет суммы его элементов оформить в виде отдельных функций
(стандартную функцию подсчета суммы элементов списка использовать нельзя)

```
from random import *

def gen_list(n, q):
    return [randrange(q) for i in range(n)]




sp = 10
n = int(input('Введите количество случайных чисел: '))
q = int(input('Введите диапазон случайных чисел: '))

lists = [gen_list(n, q) for j in range(sp)]

print('Сгенерированные списки: ', lists)
```

Comment: Так а что нестандартного? Все задания решаются с использованием базовых функций: `max`, `sum`

Answer (score -1):

```
def my_sum(array):
   sum = 0
   
   for elem in array:
       sum += elem

   return sum
```

В эту функцию передаёшь массив с элементами, которые нужно сложить, в твоём случае это lists[0], lists[1], ..., list[9]

Comment: `sum` -> `sum_` или `s`.